# Javascript comparing two dates returns NaN

Tags: javascript, string, date, titanium, appcelerator

I'm building something in javascript with Titanium Appcelerator that compares two dates.

I store expiration as a property string. The value is 2012-02-29 05:00:00 +0000
The value of current_date is 2012-03-05 22:49:54 +0000

However, when I do Date.parse on expiration its result is NaN, as compared to current_date which returns the unix timestamp 1330987794000.

Any ideas why?

```
var current_date = new Date();
var expiration = Ti.App.Properties.getString("expiration");
Ti.API.info(expiration); // returns 2012-02-29 05:00:00 +0000
Ti.API.info(current_date); // returns 2012-03-05 22:49:54 +0000

var check_expiration = Date.parse(expiration);
var check_current_date = Date.parse(current_date);
Ti.API.info(check_expiration); // returns NaN
Ti.API.info(check_current_date); // returns 1330987794000
```

Comment: What platform? What happens if you run `Date.parse()` manually in the console in that browser with the string you printed in the comments?

Comment: Date.parse oddly returned 1969-12--2147483629 -596:-31:-23 +0000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Date.parse()` does not return a `Date` instance.  Instead, it returns an integer representing the number of milliseconds since epoch.  Or if whatever it was passed wasn't parseable, it will return `NaN`.

In your code, `current_date` is an instance of `Date`.  A date object is parseable as a date, obviously.  When you log it out, it's calling `toString()` on that date object to figure out how to log it.

But `expiration` is not a `Date`, it's a string.  And the JS env of the platform you are running on does not recognize that string format as a parseable Date string.

I would suggest storing dates as integers instead.  `dateObj.getTime()` or `Date.now()` will both return integers that you can save, and then turning them back into a real date object as as simple as:

```
myDate = new Date(parseInt(dateIntegerAsString, 10));
```

Which will work reliably cross platform, and it probably much faster than the more robust date parsing you are going for here.

Answer (score 1):

A wild stab in the dark, but `current_date` is a `Date` object while `expiration` is a `String` and may be malformed to the spec required for a dateString. See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

You will need to ensure the string returned in `expiration` follows the standards.

Comment: Alright, one of my coworkers figured it out. Here it is. Guess I have to convert it to Date and remove the hyphens.

var expiration = new Date(Ti.App.Properties.getString("expiration").replace(/-/g , '/'));